# WordPress - Menu behind Slider Element

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, slider

I got a problem with a website I want to build up. The following link: http://emc.ow-media.de/

The menu layer is located behind my slider element. You can see the problem, if you hover the second menu item. I tried the following CSS code - but i didnt work:

```
.submenu {
  z-index: 9999;
}

.n2-ss-slider-1
{
    z-index:0;
}
```

Where is my mistake?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```css
submenu {
    z-index: 9999;
}
.submeu .n2-ss-slider-1
{
    z-index:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `overflow:hidden` from the below css and you are done.

```
.top_panel_middle {
    height: 130px;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}
```